# Problem with joystick

Tags: gamepad, joystick

I have a weird problem with my new joystick. One I connect it using a USB port, the device appears on the list of USB devices. If I execute the `lsusb` command it shows:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 054c:09cc Sony Corp. DualShock 4 [CUH-ZCT2x] 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1b3d Corsair Corsair Corsair Gaming K55 RGB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

You can see the second one is the DualShock 4. The problem is that neither Steam nor antimicro recognize the gamepad. The controller doesn't appear in `/dev/input` folder ether. I tried a couple of programs similar to antimicro, none of them works.

I managed to make it work once, but it didn't after that. I don´t know what exactly I do different that time. It worked with antimicro, but now not even that program works.

I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. The controller is a Noga NG-4400X.

Someone has a clue?

Comment: Some essential details are missing. What is the make/model of the device you are trying to get working? What version of Ubuntu are you using? It would also be helpful for you to describe your actions when you say "I tried everything". What did you try exactly, and what were the results of your attempts? If you managed to make it work in the past, you should also tell us what you did to make it work. With more complete details we may be able to help answer your question.

Comment: try click the 'analogue' button

Comment: Does your system have the hid_playstation or hid_sony kernel module installed? DualShock 4 is a HID gamepad but it doesn't work well with the generic HID input driver.

Comment: I updated the post to add more details